how do i solve the unmatched route problem in react native?
I'm programming in react native with expo, and whenever I click on go to homepage, it gives me unmatched route, does anyone know how to solve it?
Display the tabs on page "Homepage"
Always is "unmatched route"
Anyone Help?
Index,jsx
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Link } from 'expo-router';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
      <Text className="text-6xl font-pblack">Vibed</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <Link href="/Homepage" style={{ color: 'darkmagenta' }}>Go to
       Homepage</Link>
    </View>
  );
}


Can you share your project structure? You need to use this structure if you are using Expo.
